# Array Parameters in Axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I have a problem regarding the string array params as per the below endpoint:

Endpoint: `API/resource/Customer?fields=["*"]&filters=[["mobile_no","=","0722123456"]]`

How do I  serialize the mobile number?
My request should look as follows:

```js
axios.get('api/resource/Customer', {
  params: {
    fields: ["*"],
    filters: [["mobile_no", "=", "++"]],
  }
})
```

Comment: Was able to find a solution around it as per below:                                                                                            

someAxioMethod: (axios,phone) => {
    return axios.get('/api/resource/Customer?fields=["*"]&filters=[["mobile_no","=","'+phone+'"]] ',

);
  },

Comment: Feel free to post it as an answer.